# How to read dirty csv file in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a very dirty data that I need to read in R. The csv file seperated with comma, but there are also some commas in the first column of my data that puts me in a tight position. Something like this:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~reportname, 
  "column1, column2, column3, column4",
  "some...texts, are here with commas, www.facebook.com, 2000, 150",
  "some-texts_again_here, www.twitter.com, 1000, 50"
)
```

I now want to read it with the `read_csv`.

```
df <- read_csv('df.csv', skip = 1)
```

However, it does not match the data in correct columns since there is comma inside some of the rows of the first column. Is there a way to read the csv file accurately?

Comment: If that is truly representative, can you try to parse that in reverse order? Basically go backwards and read the two numbers, the URL, and make the rest "column1"? If you have that problem in multiple columns, it will be very tough to solve.

Comment: Have you opened it in a text editor, to get a sense of extra `,` against columns, and perhaps view it as fixed instead...? Or, perl prior to loading in R.

Comment: You need some sort of preprocessing. When I have control of the generation of .csv data, I'm careful to quote fields that might have commas, eg `"'some texts, have commas', www.facebook.com, 2000, 150"`. `read_csv` parses these correctly.

Comment: @PeterK it does not parse correctly if there are comma in the first column.

Comment: @Chris yes, I opened it. If there are commas in the text in the first column, it does not parse correctly and since data is huge it is not possible to remove them.

Comment: @datazang, `"hi, text",1,2,www.abc.com\n
smile,2,3,www.bcd.com` parses fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think your efforts should be to fix the process or person that created that CSV, as it is fundamentally broken. The code below works, but especially in R, it is inefficient, worsened with large data and R's global string hash (see https://www.brodieg.com/2019/02/18/an-unofficial-reference-for-internal-inspect/ for some discussion on this, more exists).

```r
txt <- readLines("df.csv")
# txt <- c("column1, column2, column3, column4", "some...texts, are here with commas, www.facebook.com, 2000, 150", 
"some-texts_again_here, www.twitter.com, 1000, 50")

txtspl <- strsplit(txt, ",")
ncols <- length(txtspl[[1]]) - 1L # assuming the list of column names is safe
out <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(txtspl[-1], function(z) c(paste(head(z, -ncols), collapse = ","), tail(z, ncols))))
names(out) <- txtspl[[1]]
out[] <- lapply(out, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
out
#                              column1           column2  column3  column4
# 1 some...texts, are here with commas  www.facebook.com     2000      150
# 2              some-texts_again_here   www.twitter.com     1000       50
str(out)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ column1 : chr  "some...texts, are here with commas" "some-texts_again_here"
#  $  column2: chr  " www.facebook.com" " www.twitter.com"
#  $  column3: int  2000 1000
#  $  column4: int  150 50
```

You might prefer to `trimws` your string columns.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by assuming the list of column names is safe? Because the code you shared did not give me proper output, unfortunately. :/

Comment: Ummmm ... the first line is `column1, column2, column3, column4`, which, unless a column name has an embedded comma, should be safe to just "use as is". It's a safe reference for what *should be* the number of columns in the remaining lines. This allows this code to work more generically in problems where the first column only has embedded commas, and the remaining `n-1` columns are safe.

Comment: As to not working, well, it works with the sample data provided, not sure what would be breaking it. What is not proper?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some different ways.

The first alternative makes use of the fact that regular expressions are greedy so the first .* will slurp up all text that it can while still allowing the rest of the pattern to match.

The second alternative replaces the last 3 commas with semicolons also using the fact that .* is greedy.

The third approach uses `pat` defined in the first approach and `read.pattern` from gsubfn which combines the operations.

The fourth alternative places double quotes around the first field and then reads it in using read.csv.  It uses `pat` defined in the first alternative.  It assumes that double quote is not already used.

In the first two if semicolon can appear in your file replace it in the code with any other character that does not appear.

```
# 1
pat <- "(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)"
read.csv(text = sub(pat, "\\1;\\2;\\3;\\4", df[[1]]), sep = ";", strip.white=TRUE)

# 2
Lines <- df[[1]]
for(i in 1:3) Lines <- sub("(.*),", "\\1;", Lines)
read.csv(text = Lines, sep = ";", strip.white = TRUE)

# 3
library(gsubfn)
read.pattern(text = df[[1]], pattern = pat, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)

# 4
read.csv(text = sub(pat, '"\\1",\\2,\\3,\\4', df[[1]]), strip.white = TRUE)
```